# dataWithContentsOfURL stores data in cache but not using it when using NSURLCache

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlcache

I know there're many similar questions in stackoverflow already, but they still don't clearly explain what I'm seeing.

I used

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...]
```

with NSURLCache setup and confirmed that it actually stores data in cache. (I opened up Cache.db in sqlite3 and checked the cfurl_cache_response table using "select * from cfurl_cache_response;")

It does create an entry right after dataWithContentsOfURL.

What's interesting is, even if it stored data in cache, it doesn't use it and make a network request which doesn't make sense.

I'm now thinking whether this is a bug in iOS.
Does anyone have any insight on this issue? Should I report this to Apple?

Thank you.

Comment: What was the URL? Maybe the server responded to not cache the resource.

Comment: If that was the case, it shouldn't have been stored in Cache.db. URLs with no-cache policy (or expiration date set to past) won't end up in Cache.db.